# Update previously scaffolded controllers and views after editing a model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2013, entity-framework-migrations

Recently added a custom attribute to a Model in an ASP.NET MVC project. The controller and view related with the model were generated prior to adding the Custom Attribute. I may be going the wrong way about applying this change to reflect this in the Controller and View.

Here is the Model: Custom 'SKU' atribute added

```
public class myClass {

        [Required]
        [SKU(ErrorMessage = "SKU format must be: 'M-0000'")]
        public string SKU { get; set; }
    }
```

Executed the following commands in the Package Manger Console after:

```
add-migration -ConfigurationTypeName project.Migrations.arbitraryMigration.Configuration "CustomAttributeUpdate"

update-database -ConfigurationTypeName project.Migrations.arbitraryMigration.Configuration
```

Prompted with the message:

```
Validation failed for one or more entities. See 'EntityValidationErrors' property for more details.
```

Comment: What was in EntityValidationErrors?

Comment: I am not sure how to view them. A post suggested adding a watch expression to the Watch window.  
    {    ((System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbEntityValidationException)$exception).EntityValidationErrors}

Comment: And did you try this?

Comment: I don't know what the Watch Window refers to: so I haven't added that line of code

Comment: It refers to the [debugger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sc65sadd.aspx).

Comment: That helps set me on a path to resolving the issue. I'll explore the option. Thanks for the clarification.